# Show $(1+z)^3$ is not univalent in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that $(1+z)^2$ is univalent in the unit disk.
How to show that $(1+z)^3$ is not univalent in the unit disk?

Comment: Did you try to find two elements of $\mathbb{D}$ with the same image?

Comment: I take z_1 = -3/4 + i*sqrt(3)/4 , z_2 = -3/4 - i*sqrt(3)/4 and  both are in unit disc and equal under (1+z)^3.

Comment: That would certainly do.

Comment: yaya...I can find counterexample but how to prove it generally without using the counterexample

Comment: One way of doing is by using the fact that $z^n$ is not univalent in the disk. Then there are points of $1+z$ that fall inside of the disk for which the result for the disk applies.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment above, there's no 'generality' requirement. Not being univalent is nothing more than having multiple elements being mapped to the same image.

If you're asking for an exploration of the underlying concepts, the mapping $z\mapsto z^n$ is invariant under rotations of $\frac{2\pi}{n}$. This implies that when the domain contains two points which are rotations of each other (and only then, excepting the case of $2\mid n$ and $\pm z_0$ both being elements of the domain), it fails to be univalent. Note that $\mathbb{D}-1$ is a subset of the left half-plane, but not of any cone with angle $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ for $n>2$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $z^n$; for $n>1$ is not univalent in $D$={$z:|z|<1$} , because every element in $D$ has $n$ different roots $$r^{1/n}e^{i2k\pi/n}$$, for $k=0,1,2,..,n-1$. Now, notice that there are points of the form $1+z$ that fall inside of $D$consider some tranlation-reparametrization of $(1+z)^n$ to apply the same result. Specifically, if $w$ is a point of the form $1+z$ with $|w|<1$ , then $w$ falls inside of the open disk $D$. Take, e.g., any purely negative real $z$ with $z$ in $[-1/2,0)$ . Then $|1+z|>|1-1/2|=1/2$ is in $D$ , and then the result applies.

EDIT: this may be the bottom line: if you accept that $z^n$ is not univalent on the disk, then the points of the form $1+z$ that fall inside of $D$ will have the same property as the points in $D$ for which $z^n$ is not univalent.

Comment: This explains why $z\mapsto z^n$ isn't injective, not why $z\mapsto(1+z)^n$ isn't.

Comment: O.K, I did some editing.

Comment: (1+z)^2 is univalent in the unit disk is true as it shown in the A.W.Goodman book Univalent functions. The book just say (1+z)^3 is not univalent in the unit disk and I dont have idea how to show it...

Comment: Can you see that $z^n$ itself is not univalent? $(1+z)$ is just a shift/translation of $z^n$. If you can find points of $1+z$ that fall inside of $D$ , i.e., points $w$, with $|w|<1$ , then those points will fall inside of $D$. Take, e.g., $w=-1/2$ . Then $1+w=1-1/2=1/2$. This falls inside of $D$, and it has $n$ roots.

Comment: I think it does answer the question, but I expanded on it.

Comment: It might help to explain why multiple $n$th roots fall in the translation of $\mathbb{D}$, and how this fails for $n=2$.